# How do I center text in a single line output Text widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a translation app with python dictionary; I have and entry widget (for inputting keys) and a single line Text widget (for outputting the values. I want the text outputted in the Text widget to be aligned center. I have tried tag_configure method but it's still not centering; the outputted text is still aligned left. What do I do? Thanks. Below is the code:

That is, the text widget is initially empty until a button is clicked for text in the entry widget (ent) to be translated into the text widget (output). The problem is, the text that appears in the output widget is aligned left; I want to align it center.

```
#Entry field
ent=Entry(root,width=28,justify='center',font=('Times 18'),textvar=textin,bg='white')
ent.pack()

#Output field
output = tk.Text(root)
output=Text(root,width=28,height=1,font=('Times 18'),fg="black")
output.tag_configure("center",justify='center')
output.tag_add("center",1.0,"end")
output.pack()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I center text in the Tkinter Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560585/how-do-i-center-text-in-the-tkinter-text-widget)

Comment: btw I suggest You use this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm for tkinter info, pretty great

Comment: Have you tried `anchor=CENTER` ?

Comment: How do I apply that?

Comment: When you insert text into the `Text` widget, you need to provide the tag `center` as well, like `output.insert("end", "some text", "center")`.

Answer (score 0):

You've added the tag "center" to all of the text in the widget, but there is no text in the widget. Tags have to be associated with at least one character for them to have an effect.

Comment: The text will only appear in the widget when the user clicks a button to translate the text in entry widget into text widget. Initially the text widget is blank

Comment: @DieudonneTambah: right. And like I said, the tag has to be attached to text. You can't add the tag and then add the text, unless you're adding text inside text that already has the tag. Adding a tag to an empty widget does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I merely replaced the Text widget with Entry and set the justification to center.